# Moore machine for LED display

Tags: state-machines

I want to know if my understanding of this state machine diagram is correct.

The input is connected to a toggle: 0001,1 <- This 1 represent toggling the input

Initially, when the circuit powers on, it is in state 00 and the input could either be 1 or 0.

If 1, 0001 displayed again and the input is toggled to 0.
When the input is 0 there is a state transition which displays 0010, at this state there is no toggle bit so the input is still 0, this causes a transition to the next state again

Is my understanding correct?
Thank you

[image]

Answer (score 1):

State machines have an input that by convention isn't explicitly mentioned on the state diagram: the clock. In your case, it appears that what you call "the toggle button" is used to generate the clock.

This state machine has (according to the diagram) another input that you haven't mentioned, called `Dir`. This input and the current state determine what state the machine transitions to on each clock event.

This state machine has 5 outputs. Four outputs control the 4 LEDs. The 5th output probably controls some other logic that produces the `Dir` input. Seeing what text is attached to the arrow pointing in from the right side of your image snippet might make this more clear.

All the bits indicated below the line in each state bubble indicate outputs, not inputs.

> The input is connected to a toggle: 0001,1 <- This 1 represent toggling the input

I would read it as a fifth output, not an input. Inputs should be marked along the lines, so you know what combination of inputs causes which transition.

Consider what you'd do if you had a more complex state machine with more than two possible transitions out of some of its states. Or with more than two transitions **in** to some of the states. You might even use a different set of inputs to get to state `C` from state `A` than you use to get to `C` from `B`. In that case putting the inputs needed to enter the state inside the state bubble would be very confusing.

Comment: A Moore state machine by definition is synchronous, so the clock is implied. DIR could be an external RS flip flop cleared by )) and set by 11, it does not have to be part of the internal state.

Comment: @JackCreasey, Isn't "not explicitly mentioned" the same as "implied"? And where did I say `Dir` is part of the internal state? I said "some other logic" (meaning, **not** part of this SM) produces Dir; an RS flip flop is an example of something that could be used to implement that other logic. But my guess would be `Dir` is generated by a T-flip-flop since we only have one output bit from this SM to control it, and it goes high whenever we'd want to toggle `Dir`.

Comment: Just pointing out where I thought it needed to be.

Comment: @JackCreasey, sorry, now I have no idea what you're trying to say. Where what needed to be?

Comment: I doubt DIR would be generated by a 'T' flip-flop since it is clocked. My comment was that Moore means it IS  synchronous, there is no doubt. Not all state machines MUST be synchronous. To actually answer the Op's question you really need to see the whole question, especially the elements on the LHS and RHS. I'm sorry you seemed to take offence at my comment, none was implied.

Answer (score 1):

In a Moore machine state diagram, the present state number and the system output whilst in that present state are displayed within each present state circle. This can be so because, for a Moore machine, there is only one output associated with each present state. Compare this with a mealy machine where just the state number is displayed within each state circle because there can be more than one output associated with each present state, the output being dependent on both the present state and the system input. For a Moore machine the arrows emerging from each present state circle specify (somewhere along their length) the current input during the present state from which the arrows are emerging. So for each present state and each present system input (as specified on the arrows) the destination of each arrow specifies the next state.

The 00,01,10 and 11 within the state circles are the assigned state numbers. The other 5 bits represent outputs, Of these 5 bits, the first 4 bits represent the 4 LEDs which show the chasing LED pattern and the 5th bit (after the comma) represents an output which is set when the chasing LED reaches either end of the 4 LEDs to indicate that the chasing LED has actually reached an end.

The bit shown on the arrows represents the input from the toggle switch which controls in which direction the chasing LED is moving. The lit LED moves on to the next position at the next clock edge (Moore machine outputs only respond to changes at the input at clock edges, either +ve or -ve clock edges but not both). The clock input which controls transitions between states is never shown on the state diagram.

There should be a looping arrow on state 11 which returns state 11 to itself if the input remains at 0 similar to the loop on state 00 which returns state 00 to itself if the input remains at 1.